# Laravel 5 file path error in console

Tags: laravel-5, view

I am creating a web application using Laravel 5.

I want to use AngularJS.
I have created a file named `all-products.php` in `views` directory which contains data in JSON format.

When I gave path to this file in `http.open()` it gives an error as http://localhost/user/app/resources/views/all-products.php `404 (Not Found)`.

Here is my JS code:

```
var app = angular.module("products", []);
    app.controller("productsController", function($scope, $http){
        $http.get("http://localhost/user/app/resources/views/all-products.php").success(function(response) {
            $scope.records = response.records;
        });
    });
```

Please tell me how I can solve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the file in your `public` directory e.g.

```
http.get("http://localhost/all-products.json")
```

Would be a file at path `public\all-product.json` (assuming your homepage is `http://localhost`).

Or, if the file is dynamically created, you need to create a route, and return the `.json` data from there using `Response::json(['some data]);`

Comment: Now, Laravel error: `wrapper does not support writeable connections`

Thanks for response.

Comment: are you sure thats a laravel error? - please post the whole stack message

Comment: `file_put_contents(http://localhost/user/public/all-products.php): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections`

Comment: http://localhost/all-products.json
I think that is not the path of public folder.

Comment: what is the URL of your home page? Whatever that is, that is your public path